# component does not update after an ajax call

Tags: jsf, datatable, components

Many questions very similar to this one and yet I can't see a solution.

The following code gives no error but does not behave as intended.
It displays three columns:

- 1st column is a tick box which activates the editable field for the 2nd column
- 3rd column is a row deletion method
- 4th column is just one button to move on to the next page

  ```
      <h:column>
          <h:panelGroup id="editCol">

              <f:facet name="header">
                  <h:outputText value="Edit" style="font-weight: bold">
                  </h:outputText>
              </f:facet>
              <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{m.editable}" onclick="submit()">
                  <f:ajax execute="editCol :formId:dataId:authorCol" render="editCol :formId:dataId:authorCol" />
              </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
          </h:panelGroup>

      </h:column>

      <h:column>
          <h:panelGroup id="authorCol">
              <f:facet name="header">
                  <h:outputText value="Label" style="font-weight: bold">
                  </h:outputText>
              </f:facet>
              <h:inputText value="#{m.author2displayed}" rendered="#{m.editable}" size="10"/>
              <h:outputText value="#{m.author2displayed}" rendered="#{not m.editable}"/>
              <h:commandButton value="save edits" rendered="#{m.editable}" onclick="submit()" action ="#{finalCheckBean.saveedits()}">
                  <f:ajax execute="authorCol" render="authorCol" />
              </h:commandButton>
          </h:panelGroup>
      </h:column>

      <h:column>
          <h:panelGroup id="deleteCol">
              <f:facet name="header">
                  <h:outputText value="delete row(s)" style="font-weight: bold">
                  </h:outputText>
              </f:facet>
              <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{m.deleted}" onclick="submit()"/>
              <h:commandButton value="delete row(s)?" rendered="#{m.deleted}" onclick="submit()" action ="#{finalCheckBean.deleteRow()}"/>
          </h:panelGroup>
      </h:column>

      <h:column>
          <f:facet name="header">
              <h:commandButton value="save changes" action="#{finalCheckBean.moveon}"/>
          </f:facet>

      </h:column>

  </h:dataTable>
  ```

  1. When I tick the `selectBooleanCheckbox` in the first column, the box gets ticked but nothing happens, when actually the display of components in the 2nd column should be toggled.
  2. Interestingly, when I *then* click on the `selectBooleanCheckbox` in the 3rd column, which does not use ajax, then the 2nd column gets re-rendered and I can see the effect of my tick action in step 1.

How can I make my `selectBooleanCheckbox` in first column work properly?

Comment: while working refering inside the same form no need to use all the prefixes like `:formId:dataId:authorCol` use the clean id like `authorCol` , also remove all the `onclick="submit()"` the `f:ajax` doing all the submits... (haven't read the entire question, just noticed those things...)

Comment: @Daniel This is incorrect from within a dataTable.  These id's are not in the same container as elements outside the dataTable thus he is correct to post the full id.

Comment: @seinecle Did you verify that the property for the checkbox was getting set at the managed bean when you click it?

Comment: @maple_shaft: Daniel is however right. In this context (both having the same parent `NamingContainer`), using just `authorCol` works fine and is simpler.

Comment: @BalusC I am sorry, you are right... I thought the component ActionSource was from outside the dataTable, I did not look clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox ... onclick="submit()">
    <f:ajax ... />
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

Your concrete problem is caused by having `onclick="submit()"` on the ajax checkbox. Remove it. It's triggering [`form.submit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/form.submit) which is completely conflicting the `<f:ajax>`.

You're also using it on the other ajax-less checkbox which is maybe fine, but you're also using it on the "delete row(s)?" command button which is completely unnecessary. It by default already triggers the form submit.

Comment: thx to BalusC, @Daniel and maple_shaft for the answer and comments. Works perfectly well now.